# Long range laser using wormholes

Tags: internal-consistency, spaceships, wormholes

So, I was recently watching *Stargate: Atlantis,* and I saw a very interesting concept. In one episode, the villainous Replicators use the stargate network to fire what is essentially a high-powered laser at Atlantis. My question is, *is this scientifically feasible?*

For reference, the weapon in mind produces a small wormhole going between point A (the general vicinity of a quasar) and point B (the orbit of a planet). Massive amounts of energy proceed from point A to point B via the wormhole, and then proceed to the weapon's target (point C). The beam is not a "true laser" *per se*, so much as it is a massive amount of visible-light radiation from the quasar going through the wormhole.

Comment: If you dont mind some energy loss (redshift), also this won't happen in Portal and Portal 2.

Comment: @user6760 why would traversing a portal redshift radiation?

Comment: Scientifically feasible and wormhole in one sentence?

Comment: Possible but why? Just wormhole the target into THE SPAAAACEEEEEE!

Comment: Which part is your question? Do you want to know if it makes sense to use a giant ring that makes worm holes as a weapon, but can be easily blocked by a rock? Or that you can spontaneously create wormholes from nothing and use them as a weapon?

Comment: @Trevor : I am interested in option two, because in the episode I mentioned the laser is so powerful that it burns through a sizable asteroid on its way to point C.

Comment: The smart play would be to make the 'outgoing' end of the wormhole mobile. Build a starship around it. Even in Stargate we know you can carry stargates around and use them while they're on spacecraft, so just mount your stargate to a gimbal and use it like a gun muzzle.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat the gate has to be near a planet to have the point of origin be valid.

Comment: @Trevor Are you sure? I swear I saw an episode where they used a gate that was being carried by a Goauld ship from one system to another to board the ship.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat Episode 1 of season 2.  After using the coordinates Daniel found in another reality, they jump through and find they landed on a ship.  Later on Hammond tries to use the same coordinates and fails.  They also try to escape the ship using the gate and it fails because the point of origin is wrong after they leave the planet.  The gate doesn't work again until the very end where Daniel uses Earth as the origin.  At this point the Earth now has 3 gates and is promptly forgotten :D

Comment: @Trevor Ok, so it wouldn't work in Stargate specifically, but it's certainly a viable process assuming slightly different wormhole creation mechanics.

Comment: @Trevor , Morris the Cat: For reference, I am not debating whether or not it would work in the Stargate Universe, just if it is scientifically possible. Use of stargates for the wormholes is not assumed. Also, I talking about massive amounts of directed energy coming from a wormhole, not a "true laser".

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY : Your meaning is unclear.

Comment: @thescribe YOu have two portals. Instead of spending X amount of energy through it just open in in place when the thing you want to destroy would be wormholed to the second wormhole. In space, in star, inside dense planet.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY : That is impossible in my scenario, as the mouth of the wormhole is not large enough. Plus also, the people who create the wormhole are not providing the energy, the quasar is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wormholes aren't forbidden by relativity, which isn't quite the same as "*scientifically plausible*".

If you *were* able to make a wormhole, then you'd be able to pump energy into one end and get energy out of the other end. Exactly what comes out of the other end rather depends on the nature of the wormhole metric. Given that wormholes may be mathematically possible but no-one has worked out a way to make them physically plausible, you can handwave that as you see fit. Do you want wormhole lasers? Sure, you can get wormhole lasers.

Remember that lasers aren't infinitely thin, and the throat of a wormhole is of a certain size. You can't fire a really fat beam of laser light down a really skinny wormhole. This may limit the useful range of the beam as it exits the wormhole due to diffraction limiting effects.

Finally, just because the wormhole would plausibly let you avoid the FTL issue by providing a shortcut between two points, doesn't mean that you can't just materialise a wormhole mouth at an arbitrary point in space. You need to carry one mouth to your target first (assuming that it possible, with whatever wormhole design you've settled on), and then shoot your laser through the other mouth. Being able to materialise a wormhole anywhere you like, such as by a distant target, implies FTL and *that* quickly totters off into the realms of implausibility and/or inconvenient things like time travel. So you might not want to do that, depending on how hard your want your scifi setting to be.

Comment: This raises the terrifyingly technical question “Would a laser shone through a thin wormhole diffract?”

Comment: Also worth pointing out how easily the weapon was defeated in the show. "it can't move, let's put a rock in front of it"

Comment: Assuming that you're using previously constructed wormholes as the OP's Stargate example does, the main benefit to something like this that I can see is basically allowing you have to have small warships that carry one end of the wormhole, and the actual weapon safe on a planet somewhere. This would allow fairly small warships to act as the 'muzzle' for a much larger weapon without actually having to spend energy carrying the entire weapon around. It's a slick idea imho.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat don't forget the super gate to mini gate trick. So if you fired a huge laser into a super gate, and the other side was a mini gate, does it get condensed?  And is the opposite true? Fire a tiny beam into a small gate, and output a huge beam from a giant gate?

Comment: @Trevor well, regardless of the size of the gate, matter/energy IN should always match matter/energy OUT. You could potentially FOCUS a beam by firing into a larger gate and out through a smaller one, which would be helpful for dispersion or whatever, but you couldn't turn a 5KW beam into a 50GW that way.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat It's slightly suggested that the gates did increase the energy.  To start a super gate, they needed all the energy from a planet.  But somehow the super gate was started by a small gate sitting near a black hole.  Which suggests the little gates unlimited energy was expanded to fit the big gates energy requirements.  If that is the case, you could make a telescope like system to keep powering up the beam. Scary

Comment: @MorrisTheCat : Thanks for more specifically defining my question's method. For reference, it is not a "true laser" so much as it is a massive amount of directed energy/plasma moving at high velocity

Comment: @StarfishPrime : Thank you for the answer, it is extremely informative. +1.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat - not just the size of the weapon, but its ammunition as well.  A tiny ship could launch a missile larger than it is.

Comment: @jdunlop well... maybe. You couldn't do that in Stargate anyway. It depends how much energy it takes to generate the far end of the wormhole and now large you can make it. A more reasonable option would be a small ship being able to launch a LOT of projectiles almost as large as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Reality check, if you can create worm holes anywhere.  What do you need a laser for?  Just create a wormhole that links from a black hole or star gravity somewhere, and put the other end inside the thing you want to destroy.

A laser is a waste of energy if you can already create worm holes.  And that episode in particular was pretty inconsistent and had the characters tossing idiot balls around.

Remember they couldn't move to the other side of the planet because the portable gate would follow them.  Except the portable gate couldn't get around a rock in front of it?

When gates are held open by incoming energy, they can be forced to jump to another gate by detonating a nuke next to them, they forgot that part?

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking at that particular episode so much as the general concept. Also, I specified in my question that this isn't a "true laser", as its just funneling the energy from a quasar at the target.

Comment: "When gates are held open by incoming energy, they can be forced to jump to another gate by detonating a nuke next to them, they forgot that part?" Well, not exactly. They were unable to do that because the gate was shielded from attack.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of potential issues and also potential benefits from this scenario. As noted by others wormholes, in theory at least don't (except in certain specific  circumstances) violate the laws of relativity.  So assuming they exist and assuming their internal structure doesn't somehow disrupt the path taken by photons traveling through one your laser is potentially a 'goer'.

The key problem is targeting i.e. how do you control where a wormhole opens at the other end and once its open how do you keep in stationary relative to the target. In the Star Gate franchise the gates at either end stabilize the wormhole. I haven't seen the episode you refer to but the question becomes how do the Replicators do it when as far as I'm aware Ancients couldn't. Firstly you have to be able to precisely calculate the relative distance and position of the target from your end of the wormhole across light years of distance. Then to complicate matters the planet Atlantis is on orbits it's star and the planet itself rotates on its axis. So you'd have to be able to constantly adjust the position of the exist in tandem with the motion of the target (and your end is in motion relative to the target as well just to complicate things further).

The plus side is that you could use the same technique (poring energy through a small wormhole) to power *any* ship or device anywhere in the cosmos you wanted. No need for power generators at the other end at all. Just build huge power stations somewhere at the heart of your Empire and power everything from home.